# Custom list displayed is empty

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have a donorview class which extends linearlayout which is as follows:

```
public class donorview extends LinearLayout {
private TextView donortext;
private String donorstr;
private ImageButton call;
private ImageButton msg;
private String donornumber;
private Context context1;
private View convertView;

public donorview(Context context, String donorname1, String donornum) {
    super(context);
    context1 = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listformat, null);
    convertView.setClickable(true);
    donortext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.donornametext);
    call = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.call);
    msg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    System.out.println("donorname:"+donorname1);
    System.out.println("donornum:"+donornum);
    donortext.setText(donorname1);
    System.out.println("after setting text");
    donorstr = donorname1;
    donornumber = donornum;
}

void onClickCall(){
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + donornumber));
      convertView.getContext().startActivity(callIntent);
}
public void setdonorname(String donorname12) {
    donortext.setText(donorname12);
}

public String getdonorname() {
    return this.donorstr;
}
}
```

I get a NullPoinerException as

```
java.lang.NullPonintereException
at com.wglxy.example.dash1.donorview.<init>(donorview.java:35)
```

while setting the text of the textview donortext. My XML layout of the listformat is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linerlayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/donornametext" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1" android:text="a"/>

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/call"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
        android:src="@drawable/call" android:onClick="onClickCall"
        android:background="#ffffff" />
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:contentDescription="@string/description_about"
        android:src="@drawable/msg" android:onClick="onClickMsg"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I dont understand what I am doing wrong. The list that is being displayed is empty. When i am printing the donorname and donornum it is being printed but the custom list displayed is empty.I have been trying to figure it out from a long time. Could anyone please help me with this?
My adapter code is as follows

```
   public class donorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;

ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> nums = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context context;

private String strnum;

private String strname;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;


public donorAdapter(Context context, Activity a, ArrayList<String> names,
        ArrayList<String> nums) {
    this.context = context;
    activity = a;
    this.names = names;
    this.nums = nums;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
}

public int getCount() {
    return names.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    donorview fv;
    if (convertView == null) {
        System.out.println("inside getview:"+names.get(position).toString());
        strname=names.get(position).toString();
        strnum=nums.get(position).toString();
        System.out.println("inside getview:"+nums.get(position).toString());
        fv = new donorview(context, strname,strnum);
        convertView = fv;
    }
    else {
        ((donorview) convertView).setdonorname(names.get(position)
                .toString());
    }
    convertView.setClickable(true);
    convertView.setFocusable(true);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Just Clean and Rebuilt the Project and try. Then if same Exception occurs then let me know.

Comment: Sometimes it happend if we change Some layout, then based on that the Resource id is not changing. In that case we should have to clean and rebuild the project which will alloc the resource id again and  If the Problem is regarding resource id then it can be solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use

```
donortext = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.donornametext);
```

and also replace your code by

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listformat, this);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response...the error is gone...but I am not able to see the list...I mean the list is empty...any idea??

Comment: Show us your `Adapter` code as well as how you set the adapter to `ListView`

Comment: Are your `System.out.println()` inside `getView()` got called?

Comment: yea they work perfectly fine...data is being printed in the console.

Comment: Thanks you very much Adil...it worked like a charm...but could you please explain to me the reason of putting this instead of null??

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
findViewById
```

with

```
convertView.findViewById()
```

you use findViewById, when you have already set the content for the activity, in your case you did not , so you have to specify which view it has to look to get the id. You have to do the same for the rest of your views.